# Aardvark Zebra Index / Slicing

Tags: python-3.x

I am bad in English but i will try to explain.
I started to learn python and stuck in one Aardvark Zebra Index challange, mby you know about what i speak.

I have tried everything what i can imagene, because of my bad english i dont know how to even find in google because dont know what keywords i should write to solve this problem.

1) Its the information, what i should do.
Make a function aardvark that, given a string, returns 'aardvark'
if the string starts with an a.  Otherwise, return 'zebra'.

```
aardvark("arg")

aardvark

aardvark("Trinket")

zebra
```

---

```
def aardvark(string):

    if string[0] == 'a':

        return 'aardvark'

    else:

        return 'zebra'


print aardvark("arg")

print aardvark("Apple")

print aardvark("Annie")

print aardvark("Trinket")
```

I just want to know how i can give 2 values for that if string[0] == 'a':, because i should give another value capital A, to finish this challenge. I tried many ways, but all time error..;/ Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: Try to `string[0] == 'a' or string[0] == 'A'`.

Comment: Yes, thanks, i did it myself on the end, but dont understand why it should be that difficult, vai cant just put strin[0] == 'a' or 'A' or even more easier 'a, A'. Mby someone know some better solution for this :) Thanks any way!

Comment: Yes, there it is: `string[0] in 'Aa'`.